# INSERT INTO statement- Python regex and Sqlite

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sql-insert

I'm building a program using python regex to parse emails from a text file and then add each email into the "email" column in my database.

```
import sqlite3 #imports the module

conn= sqlite3.connect('testdatabase.db') #creates a connection to the specified file. if the file does exist, it creates the file

c=conn.cursor() #allows me to create commands in this new file

#the following code creates a table with four columns
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE employees (
    'first' text,
    'last' text,
    'pay' integer,
    'email' text
    )""")

c.execute("INSERT INTO employees VALUES('Corey', 'Schafer','50000','cshafer@gmail.com')") #sample data
conn.commit() #this commits the current transaction

import re

#gets emails from a text
pattern = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+')
'''#this is the regular expression that locates the emails in my fife'''
with open('sample_data.txt') as file_handler: #this is the file I'm opening. it contains the emails I want to extract
    for line in file_handler:
        matches = pattern.findall(line)
        for match in matches:
            c.execute("""INSERT INTO employees (email) VALUES ('match')""") #this is the issue
            conn.commit()  # this commits current transaction

conn.close()  # this closes the connection to database
```

For each email in my text file, the word 'match' appears in the email column in my database. My code does not differentiate between the actual email values of match and the string 'match':
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROMzV.png

**How do I change my code so that the emails from the regex expression populate in the database instead?**

Answer (score 2):

You are passing literal string `'match'` to the query instead of the value of the variable. You want a parameterized insert:

```
for match in matches:
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO employees (email) VALUES (?)""", (match,))
    conn.commit()
```